# Get active spring profile in Angular2

Tags: angular, spring-boot

We use Angular and Spring Boot in our Web App. We have dev, test and prod spring profile which we use to load the different properties depends on the environment application run. This enables us to parametrize properties which values are different for different execution environments.

Question: Can we do the same thing on Angular side? If the "dev" spring profile is active, how to know that on Angular side?

Comment: as the name suggests, spring profile is a spring (backend) concept. Anglar cannot know about this. If you want to know, then you have to write a rest endpoint which returns active profiles. You can call this from Angular

Comment: @David It is Angular 2

Comment: @pvpkiran We have done this like this, but have troubles because Angular works faster then get request, and we have troubles regarding this. If you have some preferred way of doing this, can you please provide a link?

Comment: what do you meant by " Angular works faster then get request" ?  lets assume you got profile from backend. what do you wish to do in frontend?

Comment: @pvpkiran Thank you for help. We wish to set the value which is appropriate  for the spring profile which is active at the moment.

Comment: okay. before setting you need to call a rest endpoint and check which profile is active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a controller like this in your backend

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/profile")
public class ProfileController {

  @Autowired
  Environment environment;

  @GetMapping
  public ResponseEntity<List<String>> getCurrentActiveProfiles() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(Arrays.asList(environment.getActiveProfiles()));
  }
}
```

And call this endpoint  with Get `http://<host>:<port>/profile>` from your angular code 
and you will get a list of comma separated profile names.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {isDevMode} from '@angular/core';

if (isDevMode()) { 
   console.log('Development mode')
}
```